# Run .net website without installing MySQL ODBC 5.1 driver on system

Tags: asp.net, mysql, asp.net-mvc, odbc

I want to run my .net website without installing MySQL ODBC 5.1 driver on system. I have added myodbc5 dll in bin folder but while opening the connection it throws an exception. Exception is as follow:

```
"ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified"
```

My connection string is as follow:

```
<connectionStrings><add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=localhost;Database=demo;PORT=3306;Uid=root;Pwd=1234;OPTION=3;"/></connectionStrings>
```

I have tried to add providerName="System.Data.Odbc" in connection string but it didn't worked. I am using MySQL 5.6.11 version.
I want to run code without installing ODBC driver on my system but only including dll of odbc driver.

Please help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: if your website requires to connect to a MySql Database at startup, you _can't_

Comment: I am not connecting my website to MySql database at startup but connecting it by an inner link. On start up basic html shows.

Comment: Late comment - did you solve this problem? Can it be because the site (hosted?) does not have the "allow 32 bit" option set?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use with the MySQL Connector/NET DLL.  Just add a reference to MySql.Data.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="MySqlConnectionString" connectionString="server=MyServer;User Id=yourusername;password=yourpassword;Persist Security Info=True;database=yourdatabase" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: I am already using this for other connection string but I want to connect it from ODBC driver. I have already used as you have mention above.